# How to fix plugin could not be resolved error with maven-shade-plugin in Jetty?

Tags: xml, maven, http, jetty

I am trying to make an HTTP server **FOR THE VERY FIRST TIME** with Jetty.  I am still working at the `POM.xml` file and run into an error with the `mavin-shade-plugin`.  I think I have the correct `GroupId` and `ArtifactId` for said plugin and I am pretty sure I have the correct version (1.8).  There is a bunch of other stuff that I don't know a thing about.

the plugin tag is like this:

```xml
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                    </transformers>

                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.3.v20170317</version>
            </plugin>
```

The error is just a warning in Eclipse, and says

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin could not be resolved. Ensure the plugin's groupId, artifactId and version are present.

Additional information: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:jar:1.8 pom.xml /doecanadahttp  line 19 Language Servers
```

, but I have a feeling it would lead to an error.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output of the warning / error you are getting?

Comment: @Joakim-Erdfelt yes

Comment: But not right now since I don’t have it with me currently

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt there

Answer (score 1):

There is no version 1.8 of `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin` available on the Maven Global Repository.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Choose a different version (that exists).

Example (for version 3.2.4, that does exist):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.4</version>
  ...
```

Comment: Am I supposed to download anything (i.e. `maven-shade-plugin-[version]-javadoc.jar` or `maven-shade-plugin-[version].jar`)? If so, where should it go?

Comment: Just change the `<version>` entry to something that exists, don't download directly from the URL I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I run into a similar problem. In my case, the version was actually available in the Maven Repository.

I did "File -> Invalidate Cashes" and restarted the IDE and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason is the `--offline` mode was enabled before. So, I turned it off and it works.